# Prevent inter-namespace communication in Kubernetes

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am new to Kubernetes networking.

We have separated a Kubernetes cluster into a set of namespaces (e.g. `namespace-a`, `namespace-b`). Every namespace has a set of Kubernetes pods. Every pod has a service that is available at `my-svc.namespace-x.svc.cluster.local`.

Now, we want to **prevent** pods of namespace `namespace-a` to talk with services or pods that are part of `namespace-b` and **vice versa**. Communication **within** a namespace should be unrestricted.

This is what I found as an example in the network policies documentation:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#the-networkpolicy-resource

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

As far as I understand, this prevents network communication completely, for all pods across a namespace.

- How can I allow all network traffic, but only **within** a particular namespace?
- Do I need a networking plugin, such as Calico, Flannel or Weave? Which one should I choose?

Comment: You can find many examples of network policies here: https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Do I need a networking plugin, such as Calico, Flannel or Weave?

No matter what you need a networking plugin, but not all plugins support the `NetworkPolicy` API object. According to the [Declare Network Policy walkthrough](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/), the following is a (probably non-exhaustive) list of plugins that do support `NetworkPolicy`:

- [Calico](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/calico-network-policy/)
- [Cilium](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cilium-network-policy/)
- [Kube-router](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kube-router-network-policy/)
- [Romana](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/romana-network-policy/)
- [Weave Net](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/weave-network-policy/)

Without a plugin that supports `NetworkPolicy`, creating the resource would have no effect.

> Which one should I choose?

As for which one you should choose, stackoverflow is not the place for soliciting that kind of advice. What I can recommend is reading the overview/features documentation for the various options available. Maybe try one or two different plugins in a local development cluster to get a feel for how difficult or easy they are to install, maintain, and update.

> How can I allow all network traffic, but only within a particular namespace?

Given your example setup, I think the following `NetworkPolicy` resources would address your need:

For pods in `namespace-a`, only allow ingress from `namspace-a` pods, denying ingress from any other source. Egress is unrestricted:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: namespace-a
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: namespace-a
```

For pods in `namespace-b`, only allow ingress from `namspace-b` pods, denying ingress from any other source. Egress is unrestricted:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: namespace-b
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: namespace-b
```

Note that this assumes you have set the `name: namespace-a` and `name: namespace-b` labels on your namespaces, similar to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: namespace-a
  labels:
    name: namespace-a
    other: labelname
```

I only point this out to avoid confusing you with regard to the fact that the labels I showed above happen to match up with your hypothetical namespace names. The labels can be arbitrary and potentially inclusive of mulitple namespaces -- for example you might have `namespace-a` and `namespace-c` both with a label called `other: labelname` which would allow you to select multiple namespaces using a single `namespaceSelector` in your `NetworkPolicy` resource.